# Celery 3.1 - Executing chain of tasks asynchronicaly

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

Based on "Best Practices" in section "[Avoid launching synchronous subtasks](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks)" I would like to execute chain in background, not waiting for an job's chain result. How to achieve that ?

Is it that simple as (based on example in link I've provided)?:

```
def update_page_info(url):
    # fetch_page -> parse_page -> store_page
    chain = fetch_page.s() | parse_page.s() | store_page_info.s(url)
    chain.delay()
```

Comment: Instead of `chain.delay()` there should be `chain.apply_async()` but rest looks good. Do you have any issue / error with your code?

Comment: Please add this as an answer and I will approve it after today's night tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
chain.delay()
```

there should be

```
chain.apply_async()
```

The rest looks good.

Comment: if i want to pass a dictionary it wont work if i pass like ```def update_page_info(url*):``` how can i do this???